# Getting syntax error while running create database script in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using Node.js with mysql npm while running the below query with node js code through mysql connection

```
      var db_query=  `CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS test_db;
       USE test_db;
       DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wp_commentmeta;
    
    CREATE TABLE wp_commentmeta (
      meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      comment_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      meta_key varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      meta_value longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
      PRIMARY KEY (meta_id),
      KEY comment_id (comment_id),
      KEY meta_key (meta_key(191))
    );`



        mySqlConnection.query(db_query, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) console.log(error);

        });
```

I get the following error

```
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up ' at line 1",
```

I have tried everything possible but cant figure out whats the problem in my query
any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: Where the heck is `'s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up ` coming up in your code? Somehow that is making it into your SQL query, which I would suspect would be an INSERT statement that isn't parameterized. What you are showing us though is a CREATE TABLE and CREATE DATABASE statement which is unlikely to contain that text that threw the error. What I'm trying to say is, are you SURE this is the code that is throwing this error? I don't believe it is.

Comment: which  version are you using, not all support if exsists

Comment: We are using Mysql v 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Support for multiple statements is disabled by default for security reasons. To enable multiple statements you will need to pass the following object to createConnection function -

```
mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

More details can be found at - [doc](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries)

Comment: We have already done that but still we got the same errror.